# Move to top on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click, intro.js

I am using intro.js in my code to implement the walkthrough. I want to implement a sceanrio where on clicking the done button(.introjs-donebutton) the page should scroll to the top but with this code It is not happening. Can anyone please help me with this one?

```js
//$('.col-new-four').attr('id','essentials');
  const intro = introJs();
  
  intro.setOptions({
    steps:[
  {
      element:'#featured_apps_2_0',
      intro:'welcome'
    },
    {
      element:'#myTopnav',
      intro:'Quickly access the apps and portals you need on and off the clock.'
    },
    {
      element:'.slideshow-container',
      intro:'This space features topics you care about the most.'
    },
  {
  element:'.card',
  intro:'Stay up-to-date on trending stories.'
  },
  {
  element:'#stepextra',
  intro:'View your recommended and favorite pages.'
  },
  {
  element:'#step4',
  intro:'Find promotional content, latest additions and more here.'
  },
  {
  element:'#essentials2',
  intro:'Learn about what’s trending with your favorite topics.'
  },
  {
  element:'.col-new-7525',
  intro:'Explore benefits, tools and new features available to you.'
  }
    ]   
  })
  
  $('.introjs-donebutton').click(function() {
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
  
  function callintro(){
    intro.start();
    console.log("called intro")
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/4.2.2/intro.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: give a try to $(document).scrollTop(0);

Comment: also try $('body').scrollTop(0)

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: or you can skip jquery at all and simply use native JS by trying "window.scrollTo(0, 0);"

Comment: doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript, no framework

```js
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to scroll the client view page to top on clicking a button. if so you can use this code

HTML

```
<div class="button-parent">
   <button type="button" class="button-to-top">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button-to-top').on('click', function () {
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

Don't Forget to add jQuery cdns to your html header file. If it's not working share your html code. we will look forward

Answer (score 0):

So i used this and It started running fine, the reason being the button was dynamically being created after the inital page load, so this should work

```js
  $(document).on("click", ".introjs-donebutton", function(){
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function upsideItem() { 
    $(document).ready(function(upsideItem) { 
        $('.button-to-top').on('click', function(upsideItem) { 
            console.log(button-to-top) 
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).